# omnifaces: IllegalArgumentException FullAjaxExceptionHandler

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

I try to use the FullAjaxExceptionHandler to catch exceptions from ajax request. Unfortunely I get an IllegalArgumentException when the view expired. Below the stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Either HTTP 500 or java.lang.Throwable error page is required in web.xml or web-fragment.xml. Neither was found.
at org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandler.findErrorPageLocations(FullAjaxExceptionHandler.java:263)
at org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandler.findErrorPageLocation(FullAjaxExceptionHandler.java:228)
at org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandler.handle(FullAjaxExceptionHandler.java:165)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:113)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:409)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1534)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
at jsf.filter.MetaTagFilter.doFilter(MetaTagFilter.java:35)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
at jsf.filter.ServletExceptionFilter.doFilter(ServletExceptionFilter.java:28)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:326)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:170)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

It happens only on ajax requests. In case of a full request the page (timeout.jsp) is showing up.

Some fragments from my web.xml:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/timeout.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/error.html</location>
</error-page>
```

Webapp run on: Glassfish 3.1, JSF 2.1.0 (Mojarra), primefaces 3.3.1, omnifaces 1.1

---

UPDATE:

When I'm using facelets instead of jsp or html as errorpages I'm getting an IllegalStateException on non ajax requests. Thats why I've used html pages.

```
Warnung: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/faces/main.xhtml - Ansicht /faces/main.xhtml konnte nicht wiederhergestellt werden.
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:202)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:113)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:409)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1534)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
at jsf.filter.MetaTagFilter.doFilter(MetaTagFilter.java:35)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
at jsf.filter.ServletExceptionFilter.doFilter(ServletExceptionFilter.java:28)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:326)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:170)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Warnung: ApplicationDispatcher[/bpv-editor] PWC1231: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Context is already active
at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractConversationContext.activate(AbstractConversationContext.java:301)
at org.jboss.weld.jsf.WeldPhaseListener.activateConversations(WeldPhaseListener.java:110)
at org.jboss.weld.jsf.WeldPhaseListener.beforePhase(WeldPhaseListener.java:84)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleBeforePhase(Phase.java:228)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:99)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:113)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:409)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1534)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:787)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:649)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:454)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:350)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:474)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.dispatchToErrorPage(StandardHostValve.java:671)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:295)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.postInvoke(StandardHostValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:328)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:170)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Warnung: org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve@12d5d7d: Exception Processing    ErrorPage[exceptionType=javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException, location=/WEB-INF/errorpages/timeout.xhtml]
javax.servlet.ServletException: Context is already active
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:422)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1534)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:787)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:649)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:454)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:350)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:474)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.dispatchToErrorPage(StandardHostValve.java:671)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:295)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.postInvoke(StandardHostValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:328)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:170)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Context is already active
at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractConversationContext.activate(AbstractConversationContext.java:301)
at org.jboss.weld.jsf.WeldPhaseListener.activateConversations(WeldPhaseListener.java:110)
at org.jboss.weld.jsf.WeldPhaseListener.beforePhase(WeldPhaseListener.java:84)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleBeforePhase(Phase.java:228)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:99)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:113)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:409)
... 27 more
----- Root Cause -----
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Context is already active
at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractConversationContext.activate(AbstractConversationContext.java:301)
at org.jboss.weld.jsf.WeldPhaseListener.activateConversations(WeldPhaseListener.java:110)
at org.jboss.weld.jsf.WeldPhaseListener.beforePhase(WeldPhaseListener.java:84)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleBeforePhase(Phase.java:228)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:99)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:113)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:409)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1534)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:787)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:649)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:454)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:350)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:474)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.dispatchToErrorPage(StandardHostValve.java:671)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:295)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.postInvoke(StandardHostValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:328)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:170)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: This is strange. What if you try `<exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>` instead? By the way, the error page must be a Facelets file, not a JSP or HTML file, but that's a different problem.

Comment: The Problem was that the errorpages weren't facelets. I changed them and it's working now. Many Thanks.

Comment: This is strange. The `IllegalArgumentException` should only have occurred when no one HTTP 500 or `Throwable` entry can be found, regardless of the file type. Are you certain that you did properly rebuild/redeploy the webapp after editing the `web.xml`? As to the new `IllegalStateException` problem, this is a Weld-specific issue. I recall having seen it and that it has been fixed in a newer Glassfish version. Try upgrading Glassfish. The error page must be a JSF/Facelets page, because plain JSP/HTML files are not supported in JSF ajax responses.

Comment: Sure I rebuild and redeploy my webapp after changing the web.xml. And accroding to the Weld-specific issue I also try Glassfish 3.1.2 and get the same exception `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: Regarding to the `IllegalArgumentException` I have tested it again with html files as locations and there is none anymore. I hope you didn't worry about it to much. I'm sorry.

Comment: Okay, you have now no problems left?

Comment: Yes I have. There is still the `IllegalStateException` problem with a facelet as location. But when I locate the `ViewExpiredException`to a jsp file the ajax and non ajax requests are catched.

Comment: Okay, thank you for sharing this information. As to the `IllegalStateException`, this is still Weld-specific.